# VBA Double variables assigned to each other causes a Run-time error '6' Overflow

Tags: excel, vba, macos, vba7

Mac OS 13.5.1, Microsoft 365 Excel for Mac 16.78 , VBA 7.1

Two variables of type Double when assigned to each other generate a Run-time error '6': Overflow.
Example code below.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test2()
    Dim a As Double
    Dim b As Double
    
    
    a = 0
    b = 10
    Debug.Print a; b
    a = b
    'a = Round(b, 10)
    Debug.Print a; b
End Sub
```

If the assigning variable is processed with the VBA Function Round the run-time error does not occur (see comment line in the code). Also, if the variables are type Variant or any other type the problem does not occur.
This code can't get simpler, and Type Double should be able to be assigned to Type Double.
This must be a bug.

Comment: I am yet to get the overflow error with your code, w/ or w/o the Round, all works just fine.

Comment: This is a well-known (intermittent) bug in VBA for Mac. Use Variant instead of Double to avoid it, or switch to Windows :-)

Comment: Later in the day, MS updated Excel to version 16.78 (23090401), and the problem has been fixed.